# Backbone event not firing on click - not specifying events correctly?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, dom-events, backbone-events

In this backbone view, the view is getting initialized, but the insertLink event is not being triggered when the button with the ".insert-link" class is clicked.  Is there something I am missing having to do with binding the event?

```
MyView.Show = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    "click .insert-link": "insertLink"
  },

  initialize: function(options) {
    _.bindAll(
              this,
              "insertLink"
              );
  },

  insertLink: function(e){
    console.log("triggered at last!");
  }
});
```

this is the relevant part of the DOM:

```
<div id="insert_link">
    <a href="#" class='insert-link btn btn-mini' data-landing-page-id="<%= current_user.default_landing_page_id.to_s %>">
        Insert Link
    </a>
</div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    new MyView.Show({
      el: $('#insert_link')
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: How does your dom look like?

Comment: Hi Trunal I added the DOM

Comment: oops - ok, el is there now

Comment: does el also need to be set explicitly in the javascript file?

Comment: You have a element with a id here `div id="insert_link">` and you are attaching a event to the class  `"click .insert-link": "insertLink"`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected in isolation (http://jsfiddle.net/7nYhD/1/)

```
var MyView = {};

MyView.Show = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click .insert-link": "insertLink"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {
       _.bindAll(
          this,
          "insertLink"
          );
    },

    insertLink: function(e){
        console.log("triggered at last!");
    }
});

$(function(){
   new MyView.Show({
     el: $('#insert_link')
   });
 });
```

This implies your problem is more likely to be with: scripts being loaded in the wrong order, using old versions of scripts, or when your code is executed before it has full access to the dom.

Check all of those things, and if you still have an issue, perhaps you provide more details/code.